# Association on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a soccer match in which two teams will participate, one is the "home team" and one is the "away team".

So, in DB , table "matches" I have:

```
home_team_id - integer column
away_team_id - integer column
```

In Match class the Scopes:

```
belongs_to :team_home, foreign_key: :home_team_id, class_name: 'Team'
belongs_to :team_away, foreign_key: :away_team_id, class_name: 'Team'
```

Which is the corrent association to put in Team class so I can retrieve all matches for a team, both home that away matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is one possible solution

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :home_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "home_team_id"
  has_many :away_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "away_team_id"

  def myMatches
    Match.where("home_team_id = ? OR away_team_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
  end

end

class Match  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "home_team_id"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "away_team_id"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Richi. And how about the "OR" condition? It will be performant in case of million of records, or maybe it will be preferible a new join table, like teams_matches with team_id and match_id columns (2 row for 1 match) ?

Comment: its only a posseble solution, joining is another - in myMatches you can retrieve all matches for a Team - which was the question